# Is there any example of using mbind in C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, numa

I am trying to use [mbind()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mbind.2.html) in my C++ code in order to rearrange virtual pages across 4 NUMA domains, unfortunately I am new to this function:

```
long mbind(void *addr, unsigned long len, int mode, const unsigned long *nodemask,   
              unsigned long maxnode, unsigned flags);
```

Currently, I have something like this:

```
mbind(0x0,4611686018424767488,MPOL_BIND,nodemask,maxnode,MPOL_MF_MOVE);
```

From the specs it's still unclear to me what to put and how to put for `nodemask` and `maxnode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodemask` is a pointer to a bitmask of the allowed NUMA nodes. The bitmask is an array of `unsigned long` elements with each array element holding as many bits as the size of `unsigned long int` on the particular architecture allows. Unless your program is running on a really big NUMA system, a single `unsigned long` variable should suffice.

`maxnode` gives the number of significant bits in `nodemask`. The kernel rounds internally the size to a multiple of `sizeof(unsigned long)` but only uses `maxnode` bits.

There are many examples and libraries around that allow you to create and conveniently manipulate bitmasks without having to fiddle with bit operations yourself. You can utilise `libnuma`. It doesn't allow you to set the `MPOL_MF_MOVE` policy but includes functions for the creation and manipulation of nodemasks.

**A terrible and very unportable Linux pro-tip:** The existing macros that deal with the CPU affinity masks, namely `CPU_ZERO` / `CPU_SET` / `CPU_CLR` and the associated data structure `cpu_set_t` can also be used for NUMA nodemasks. The reason for that is that (1) both are implemented as arrays of `unsigned long` and (2) there are usually less NUMA nodes than logical CPUs, therefore `cpu_set_t` should have enough bits to be able to represent all NUMA nodes on the system.

Side note: `4611686018424767488` should probably be suffixed with `LL`.

Comment: now i'm suffering with following:

...
  CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
  CPU_SET(0, &cpu_set);
...
  CPU_SET(7, &cpu_set);
  sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set);
  nodemask = 8;
  //ret = set_mempolicy(MPOL_BIND, &nodemask, sizeof(nodemask)*8);                                                                                                                                          
  ret = mbind(0, 12884901888, MPOL_BIND, &nodemask, sizeof(unsigned long), MPOL_MF_MOVE);

this works with set_mempolicy (commented line), but doesn't work with mbind. could u pls help here? tnx!